# constructor not updating local variables

Tags: c#, variables

I have the following classes:

```
  public class Core {
       SyncList<myItem> ITEM = new SyncList<myItem>;

       public void addSubitem(){
           subItem i = new subItem();
           i.itemType = "TYPE1"; // not updating
           ITEM[0].sItem.Add(i);
       }
  }

  public class myItem {
       public SyncList<subItem> = sItem new SyncList<subItem>();
  }

  public class subItem {

       public string itemType { get; set; }

       public subItem(){
           this.itemType = "TYPE1"; // not updating
       }
  }
```

This is how I define it on main form:

```
public static Core core { get; set; }
core = new Core(); // assigned in form constructor
```

this is how I call it onClick event:

```
core.addSubitem();
```

But it doesn't update and the itemType variable is null all the time. I don't understand why is this happening.. any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your code does not compile.

Comment: Classes are not defined with parentheses.

Comment: Have you tried creating it using Core myCore = new Core() first?

Comment: also, it should be `i.itemType =` not `i.ItemType` - Inside the `subItem` class, it is defined in camelCase

Comment: @Andrew yes I did in form constructor, forgot to add it in the example

Comment: what is `core.Item` i see no such property/field

Comment: Please, copy/paste the actual code that you have compiled. There are many mistakes in this

Comment: As Romoku said, classes are not defined with parantheses. Plus your classes names must begin with a capital letter for convention reasons. Same for the properties.

Comment: `core.ITEM` is a `List<Item>`, so `core.Item[0]` (the list entry at position 0) is of type `Item` and `Item` does not have a method `addSubitem()`. Maybe you meant `core.addSubitem()`? (Btw, `core.Item[0]` is probably `null` in this case anyway...)

Comment: @Corak yes, that's what I ment, fixed the code. I just don't understand how can constructor NOT update a local variable

Comment: `ITEM[0].sItem.Add(i);` still won't work, because `ITEM[0]` is invalid at this point (you will get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException trying to access it). You need to add something to `ITEM` before you can work with it's zero'th element!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a SubItem into your Item list.
You can't do it directly like you try to do.

Here is what I suggest:

```
 public class Core {
       public SyncList<MyItem> Items{get; private set;}

       public Core(){
            Items = new SyncList<MyItem>;
       }

       public void AddSubItem(){
            MyItem item = new MyItem();
            SubItem i = new SubItem();
            i.ItemType = "TYPE1";
            item.SubItems.Add(i);
            Items.Add(item);           
       }
  }

  public class MyItem {
       public SyncList<SubItem> SubItems {get; private set;}

       public SubItem(){
            SubItems = new SyncList<SubItem>();
       }
  }

  public class SubItem {

       public string ItemType { get; set; }
  }
```

Then in your main form:

```
public static Core Core { get; set; }
Core = new Core(); // assigned in form constructor
```

And in your click event, call your method like this:

```
Core.AddSubItem();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is SyncList but I tried your code with List<>(). There were some problems and it works now.

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Core
    {
        List<MyItem> MyItemList = new List<MyItem>();

        public void AddSubitem()
        {
            SubItem sItem = new SubItem();
            sItem.ItemType = "TYPE2"; // it's updating

            MyItem mItem = new MyItem();
            this.MyItemList.Add(mItem);

            this.MyItemList[0].sItem.Add(sItem);
        }
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public List<SubItem> sItem = new List<SubItem>();
    }

    public class SubItem
    {
        public string ItemType { get; set; }

        public SubItem()
        {
            this.ItemType = "TYPE1"; // it's updating
        }
    }
}
```

After below code ItemType's value is TYPE2.

```
Core core = new Core();
core.AddSubitem();
```